# Structural descriptions of neuronal networks are important for understanding brain dysfunctions; which dysfunctions, in particular?

Tags: neuroscience, neural-network, neurology

In a recent paper, we find this quote:

> The brain contains vast numbers of interconnected neurons that constitute anatomical and functional networks. **Structural descriptions of neuronal network elements and connections** make up the “connectome” of the brain (Hagmann, 2005; [Sporns et al., 2005](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pcbi.0010042); [Sporns, 2011](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1749-6632.2010.05888.x)), and **are important for understanding normal brain function and disease-related dysfunction**.

This quote is from the first paragraph in: T. B. Leergaard, C. C. Hilgetag and O. Sporns, *[Mapping the connectome: multi-level analysis of brain connectivity](http://dx.doi.org/10.3389/fninf.2012.00014)*, Front. Neuroinform., 2012.

> **Question**: Understanding which dysfunctions, in particular, is aided by structural descriptions of neuronal networks?

Answer (score 2):

[Stam et al.](https://www.vumc.nl/afdelingen-themas/33760/101392/1207788/stam-brain2009.pdf) have carried out a functional connectivity study in patients with Alzheimer's Disease. I don't know if that answers your question at all. Connectomics is just starting to kick off. It's far from certain that they it will end up being a key player in functional neuropathology in the coming decades, but it's one out of many promising new avenues of research.

Comment: Fascinating find! Welcome to cogsci.SE!